# Setup ansible module proxmoxer

Tags: ansible, proxmox

I got near zero skills with ansible.

I need to setup the proxmoxer module to do verify_ssl=false because i have  this kind of error :

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='curiosity', port=8006): Max retries exceeded with url: /api2/json/access/ticket (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f21f8f679d0>, 'Connection to curiosity timed out. (connect timeout=5)'))
```

I read the documentation saying it's possible to change the backend with openssh or ssl verification option :

https://proxmoxer.github.io/docs/1.2/basic_usage/

As i never wrote an ansible plugin i got zero idea how i can setup this module.

I tried to edit :

/lib/python3.10/site-packages/proxmoxer/core.py

but got no clue what to do.

Need a hint please.

Thanks.

Comment: `verify_ssl=false` will not resolve a timeout error. A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. I checked if the api is working ans it is : curl -k -d 'username=root@pam' --data-urlencode 'password=mypassword' https://myhostip:8006/api2/json/access/ticket that is why i'm puzzled .

Comment: The command you used to check it uses http while Ansible uses https. Check it with https.

Comment: `curl -k -d 'username=root@pam' --data-urlencode 'password=mypassword' https://curiosity:8006/api2/json/access/ticket` is working.

Comment: also i can ssh into proxmox and access webui without problem from the same client.